# Determining the properties of a set (whether it is affine, convex or a polyhedron)

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

$ \text{If } S = \{\alpha \in R^3 | \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 e^{-t} + \alpha_3 e^{-2t} \leq 1.1 \text{ for } t \geq 1\}$, then

1) S is affine

2) S is convex

3) S is a polyhedron

Questions:

1) Is an affine set the same thing as an affine hull?

I've only had a handwavy background in convexity so I think of something being affine as it being a straight line translated on some axis so I don't think that this is true?

2 & 3) I have no intuition regarding convexity and polyhedron. I'm thinking of choosing some arbitrary $\alpha_a \text{ and } \alpha_b$ and going through the definition. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

**Partial answer:**

An *affine hull* is a particular affine set (smallest affine set containing the given set).

An *affine set* can be thought of as a translation of a vector space; your example is correct, but it could also be a translated plane etc.